# How can I get the variance between two datatables?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datatable, dataset

I am trying to do a simple financial table that compares the actual to the budgeted figures and show the variance.

```
**Actual**
ID          Revenue
1           100
2           120

**Budget**
ID          Revenue
1           120
2           100
```

Once compared it will give me this table:

```
**Variance**
ID          Revenue
1           -20
2           +20
```

This is how I got my two tables setup right now:

```
        // Make the Actual table
        DataTable allActual = new DataTable("actualTable");
        DataRow rowActual;

        // Create columns and add to the DataTable.
        allActual.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        allActual.Columns.Add("Revenue", typeof(string));

        // Add rows to the Actual grid
        foreach (SPListItem item in actualItems)
        {
            rowActual = allActual.Rows.Add();
            rowActual["Title"] = item["Title"].ToString();
            rowActual["Revenue"] = item["Revenue"].ToString();
        }


        // Make the Budget table
        DataTable allBudget = new DataTable("budgetTable");
        DataRow rowBudget;

        // Create columns and add to the DataTable.
        allBudget.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        allBudget.Columns.Add("Revenue", typeof(string));

        // Add rows to the Actual grid
        foreach (SPListItem item in budgetItems)
        {
            rowBudget = allBudget.Rows.Add();
            rowBudget["Title"] = item["Title"].ToString();
            rowBudget["Revenue"] = item["Revenue"].ToString();
        }
```

I would appreciate any help in pointing me to the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: How about creating a view at the database to do the subtracting?

Comment: The data is held within SharePoint lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ-To-DataSet to get the difference:

**Edit**: Here is the C# version of the Dictionary-approach(use a simple `ToList` to get a list of this anonymous type):

```
var diff = (from  aRow in tblActual.AsEnumerable()
            join bRow in tblBudget.AsEnumerable()
            on aRow["ID"] equals bRow["ID"]
            let aRev = (int)aRow["Revenue"]
            let bRev = (int)bRow["Revenue"]
            where aRev != bRev
            select new 
            {
                ID = (int)aRow["ID"],
                Diff = aRev - bRev
            }).ToDictionary(r => r.ID, r=> r.Diff );
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim diff = (From aRow In tblActual
            Join bRow In tblBudget _
            On aRow("ID") Equals bRow("ID")
            Let aRev = DirectCast(aRow("Revenue"), Int32)
            Let bRev = DirectCast(bRow("Revenue"), Int32)
            Where aRev <> bRev
            Select New With {.ID = DirectCast(aRow("ID"), Int32),
                            .Diff = aRev - bRev}).ToList


For Each d In diff
    Dim id = d.ID
    Dim revDifference = d.Diff
Next
```

Or create a Dictioary(Of Int32, Int32) if you want to lookup a difference for a given ID:

```
Dim diff = (From aRow In tblActual
            Join bRow In tblBudget _
            On aRow("ID") Equals bRow("ID")
            Let aRev = DirectCast(aRow("Revenue"), Int32)
            Let bRev = DirectCast(bRow("Revenue"), Int32)
            Where aRev <> bRev
            Select New With {.ID = DirectCast(aRow("ID"), Int32),
                            .Diff = aRev - bRev}).
                            ToDictionary(Function(r) (r.ID), 
                                         Function(r) (r.Diff))

' returns diff for a given ID '
Dim diffForID2 = diff(2)
' iterate all dictionary entries '
For Each d In diff
    Dim id = d.Key
    Dim revDifference = d.Value
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to write this in C# so I cannot accept this answer.

Comment: @David: I can try to translate to C# although common tools fail to do so.

Comment: Dear Tim, that worked fine. Do you know how I name the columns? It is coming up as "Key" "Value" at the moment.

Comment: @David: As i've said, if you don't need the Dictionary, you simply need to replace the `ToDictionary` part with `ToList()`. Then you get a list of that anonymous type with two properties: 1.ID 2.Diff. You can rename them if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much that works fine as well. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a straight forward one-to-one relationship between the Actual and Budget lists why not perform the calculation while reading each list item? Here's some pseudo-code:

```
//actuals contains all the list items from the Actuals list
//budget contains all the list items from the Budget list
//variance is an array of numbers with the same length as the actuals list
for (i=0; i<actuals.length; i++)
{
 diff = actuals[i].value - budget[i].value;
 variance[i] = diff;
}
```